# Angular 4 animation does left, right, top, bottom correctly but does not work for transforms (translateX,translateY,translateZ)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-animations

I am trying to animate router transitions using angular 4.1.2 using the pseudo `:enter`, `:leave` state change expressions using 3D CSS expressions.

Read the [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/animations#example-entering-and-leaving) docs on this which describe `void => *` and `* => void` for `:enter` and `:leave` pseudo transitions.

After trying the `slide in out` transformation from [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/04/19/angular-2-4-router-animation-tutorial-example), I could eventually get it to work by setting `:host {postion:relative}` in my component css files(should prob let the author know).

This worked:

```
trigger('routerAnimation', [
    transition(':enter', [
        style({ right: '-400%' }),
        animate('.2s ease-in-out', style({ right: 0 }))
    ]),

    transition(':leave', [
        animate('.2s ease-in-out', style({ right: '-400%' }))
    ])
]);
```

This did not:

```
trigger('routerAnimation', [
    transition(':enter', [
        style({ transform: 'translateZ(-400px)' }),
        animate('.2s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateZ(0)' }))
    ]),

    transition(':leave', [
        style({ transform: 'translateZ(0)' }),
        animate('.2s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateZ(-400px)' }))
    ])
]);
```

I am really confused as to why this is happening, I also tried setting my `:host` positioning from `relative` to `absolute` just to be sure I am not making a CSS mistake.

Any help would be super duper mega awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add transform: perspective(XXXpx);
That's why you just can't see translateZ effect.
I tried to use such animation:

```
import { animate, AnimationEntryMetadata, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/core';

// Component transition animations
export const slideInDownAnimation: AnimationEntryMetadata =
  trigger('routeAnimation', [
    state('*',
      style({
        opacity: 1,
        transform: 'perspective(500px) translateZ(0px)',
      })
    ),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({
        opacity: 0,
        transform: 'perspective(500px) translateZ(-400px)',
      }),
      animate('10s ease')
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate('10s ease', style({
        opacity: 0,
        transform: 'perspective(500px) translateZ(-400px)',
      }))
    ])
  ]);
```

And it works just fine.
Check this to find more about translateZ:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d

If your components are bigger than screen you will not see animation or you need to scroll the page to find it. So in most cases you need to add position:absolute to the component CSS (for :host selector). Or you can add such decorated properties:

```
@HostBinding('@routeAnimation') public routeAnimation = true;
@HostBinding('style.display')   display = 'block';
@HostBinding('style.position')  position = 'absolute';
```

Don't forget to add:

```
import {HostBinding} from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Thanks, for the tip. I tried this and found that the new route state pushes in, on top of the old one and just hangs around for 10s and then suddenly vanishes without any transition or effect. Strange ...

Comment: Dima, you were right, perspective eventually did the trick but the web component needs to have `position:absolute` for translations to work. I made it relative to enable the animation of the css `right` property from the tutorial. Not setting the `position` at all will give the impression that nothing works as one would expect. If you update your answer to include this information it would be very handy for the person googling the problem. Thank you!